# How to convert list of list (of lists) to json array in python?

Tags: python, json, list

I'm having trouble finding how to convert python list of of elements like this:

```
[[["thisid", 24024502], ["points", [[["lat", 37.8732041], ["lon", -122.2562601]], [["lat", 37.8729153], ["lon", -122.2561566]]]], ["name", "Latimer Hall"]]
```

to json array of elements like that:

```
{"thisid": 24024502, "points": [{"lat": 37.8732041, "lon": -122.2562601}, {"lat": 37.8729153, "lon": -122.2561566}], "name": "Latimer Hall"}
```

Basically, I'm trying to convert list of lists with inner structure to a corresponding list in json.

Plain `json.dumps(mylist)` just returns the original list (I guess, it's because it's a valid json object as well...)

Many thanks for any suggestions you may have!

Comment: Why aren't you using a dictionary for the original data? That would be easier to use, and also serialize into the JSON you're looking for.

Answer (score 5):

The parentheses in your original code are unbalanced. If I remove one parentheses in the beginning:

```
>>> a = [["thisid", 24024502], ["points", [[["lat", 37.8732041], ["lon", -122.2562601]], [["lat", 37.8729153], ["lon", -122.2561566]]]], ["name", "Latimer Hall"]]
>>> b = dict(a)
>>> for i, l in enumerate(b['points']):
...     b['points'][i] = dict(l)
... 
>>> b
{'points': [{'lat': 37.8732041, 'lon': -122.2562601}, {'lat': 37.8729153, 'lon': -122.2561566}], 'thisid': 24024502, 'name': 'Latimer Hall'}
>>>
```

Then I can serialize it to json.