# How to convert python list to json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7

How to convert list to json :

list is :

```
cords = [ [20.339751164468076, 85.8083048318772], [20.339866852950124, 85.80909340132757]]
```

and I want to convert that list into json like this:

```
json_cords = [
    {
        'lat': 20.339751164468076,
        'lon': 85.8083048318772
    },
    {
        'lat': 20.339866852950124,
        'lon': 85.80909340132757
    }
]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to convert list of list (of lists) to json array in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769811/how-to-convert-list-of-list-of-lists-to-json-array-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use the below dictionary comprehension:

```
import json
cords = [ [20.339751164468076, 85.8083048318772], [20.339866852950124, 85.80909340132757]]
print(json.dumps([{'lat':x,'lon':y} for x,y in cords],indent=4))
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        "lat": 20.339751164468076,
        "lon": 85.8083048318772
    },
    {
        "lat": 20.339866852950124,
        "lon": 85.80909340132757
    }
]
```

Comment: Did not downvote. That's not JSON. But fairly speaking the example output of the OP is neither.